# EventHandler, HttpRequest and uploading file via HTTP PUT

Tags: 2013, rest, event-receivers

I'm trying to develop and event handler which reads PDF files in `ItemAdding` method.

After reading a bit on the internet, I finally [found a way to do so](https://williamvanstrien.blogspot.com/2011/10/read-content-of-uploaded-file-within.html).

When uploading a file through a browser, everything works as intended. But when use a script executing a raw HTTP PUT, it does not work anymore. I get a null `HttpContext.Current` in the event constructor.

My guess is that when doing an HTTP PUT, I'm not in an `HttpContext` but in something else, like an `OperationContext` or a `WebOperationContext`, [like explained on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904313/access-httpcontext-current-from-wcf-web-service/5904345#5904345).

But if I try to get a current `OperationContext` or `WebOperationContext`, it returns null.

Is there anything I should know here?

Answer (score 0):

You definetely can't rely on the current `HTTPContext`, or even on `SPContext.Current`, since uploads can occur from direct OM calls (PowerShell, consol apps, ...). And in these cases, there's no context at all, only direct connections to the SQL DB from the process running the code (PowerShell, console app...).
I always have this simple rule of thumb: no `HTTPContext.Current` or `SPContext.Current` in event receivers. I've seen this error (that leads to immediate crashes) a lot in projects I audit. Don't assume upload is done from the Web context.

The only option I can see here is to read the content from a synchronous `ItemAdded`, remove the file if you don't like it, and raise an error after deleting it.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the fast answer.

I totally understand that it's a bad idea to use HttpContext.Current.

So let's say I want to raise an error after deleting the wrong file. I can't find a way to return an error code when doing so ?
If i change `properties.Status` to an Error in ItemAdded, I still get a "200 OK" to the PUT request.
Throwing an exception does not change the HTTP return code either.

Comment: ItemAdded is executed asynchronous by Default. So the Item will be added and you get a OK. You don´t get direct Responses from asynchronous Events. Use ItemAdding instead (or, not recommenced, Change the execution of your itemAddedReceiver to synchronous manually).